# The right service to listen to iot-hub and send queries to Azure SQL

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-iot-hub

I'd like to build a small solution on Azure for practice. I'd be sending data using IOT-HUB from some devices and what I need is some way to interpret this data and do appropriate query to Azure SQL.

Basically I would need a way to have my program running all the time being able to:

- listen to events from iot-hub
- interpret event information and save/get data to/from database
- send a message to some device using iot-hub

Which service would be good for that? Am I able to use Entity Framework?
In ideal solution I'd create a C# program to do what I need and have it running in Azure, waiting for events from iot-hub, having access to my database - is it even possible?
I'm very new (rather completely new) to cloud solutions, so I'd be really grateful for any advices. Currently I feel completely lost in all these Azure services.

Comment: Have you check [Azure Function](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/) ?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Yes, i just recently started to use them. I think it's a pretty good solution for my needs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is quite some documentation on Azure IoT and how one can possible architect an IoT solution.

1. The [IoT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-suite/iot-suite-what-is-azure-iot) is the obvious first step to get an overview of what Azure offers. There are some nice 'Getting Started' walkthroughs also
2. Take a look at this [IoT reference architecture](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjDrdy9zJLVAhUHU1AKHRxjDRgQFghYMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2FA%2F4%2FD%2FA4DAD253-BC21-41D3-B9D9-87D2AE6F0719%2FMicrosoft_Azure_IoT_Reference_Architecture.pdf&usg=AFQjCNH7R3_CUnab108Tw4ll-VT2J3o_5g). Quite helpful to get an overview.

There are tons of links and interesting examples for Azure IoT. Just google around.

Comment: Thanks for this nice document about IoT, I didn't see it before. Doesn't answer my question, but surely a good read.